# can't get logging to work on mariadb

Tags: mysql, logging, mariadb

I'm trying to get the general logging in mariadb enabled so i can see all the queries being generated against my database.

I'm running version 5.5 on ubuntu:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%Version';
+------------------+---------------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                           |
+------------------+---------------------------------+
| innodb_version   | 5.5.43-MariaDB-37.2             |
| protocol_version | 10                              |
| version          | 5.5.44-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1 |
+------------------+---------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

In my my.cnf file, here's what I've attempted to add in the [mysqld] section:

```
general-log
general-log-file=queries.log
log-output=file
```

The reference I was using can be found here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/general-query-log/

When I restart my database using "/etc/init.d/mysql restart", and I start requesting pages via my web application, I can't find any log files being generated eventhough I'm certain the database is being queried.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1**

Upon closer examination, I've noticed that the error log isn't working either. 
When I restart mysql, I get the following messages:

```
myuser@dev:/etc/mysql$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
 * Stopping MariaDB database server mysqld                                                                                       [fail] 
 * Starting MariaDB database server mysqld                                                                                       [ OK ]
```

Notice how the stop command fails.  But I can't find any error logs. 
This is my entire msqld section in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
general-log
general-log-file=queries.log
log-output=file
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

**EDIT 2**

Results from "show variables like '%log%'" command is pasted here: 
http://pastebin.com/Zt8xFxLN

Line 18 seems to be my problem and maybe line 30 for the error logs? 
If i change these values via command line, will it only last for the current session?

Comment: What does `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log%';` tell you?

Comment: @vhu please see edit 2

Answer (score 1):

Something stood out to me while reading the documentation in your first link:

> By adding this to your my.cnf file all queries will be logged to the file queries.log in the datadir directory.

So, I enabled it and had a look at the contents of /var/lib/mysql (the mysql/mariadb datadir).

And there it was - queries.log

The datadir isn't exactly where I'd expect it to be either, but the docs say so.  I'd rather see it in /var/log/mysql (it is a log, after all), so I changed the above configuration to a full path (/var/log/mysql/queries.log).  The result is as expected, the log ends up in /var/log/mysql

yay!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that things changed since this  discussion. As of today, I can enable logging with

```
mysql -e "SET GLOBAL general_log=1;" 
mysql -e "SET GLOBAL general_log_file='all_query.log';" 
less +F /var/lib/mysql/all_query.log
```

Note that the file appears in /var/lib/mysql, rather than in /var/log/mysql ...

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following command on the mysql commandline:

```
set global log="on"
```